# WatchService fires ENTRY_MODIFY sometimes twice and sometimes once

Tags: java, rhel, watchservice, nio2

I am using this `WatchService` example from Oracle:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WatchDir {

private final WatchService watcher;
private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;
private final boolean recursive;
private boolean trace = false;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
    return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
}

/**
 * Register the given directory with the WatchService
 */
private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
    if (trace) {
        Path prev = keys.get(key);
        if (prev == null) {
            System.out.format("register: %s\n", dir);
        } else {
            if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                System.out.format("update: %s -> %s\n", prev, dir);
            }
        }
    }
    keys.put(key, dir);
}

/**
 * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
 * WatchService.
 */
private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
    // register directory and sub-directories
    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException
        {
            register(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
 */
WatchDir(Path dir, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
    this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
    this.recursive = recursive;

    if (recursive) {
        System.out.format("Scanning %s ...\n", dir);
        registerAll(dir);
        System.out.println("Done.");
    } else {
        register(dir);
    }

    // enable trace after initial registration
    this.trace = true;
}

/**
 * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
 */
void processEvents() {
    for (;;) {

        // wait for key to be signalled
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            return;
        }

        Path dir = keys.get(key);
        if (dir == null) {
            System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
            continue;
        }

        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

            // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
            if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }

            // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
            Path name = ev.context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);

            // print out event
            System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);

            // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
            // register it and its sub-directories
            if (recursive && (kind == ENTRY_CREATE)) {
                try {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        registerAll(child);
                    }
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    // ignore to keep sample readbale
                }
            }
        }

        // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            keys.remove(key);

            // all directories are inaccessible
            if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void usage() {
    System.err.println("usage: java WatchDir [-r] dir");
    System.exit(-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // parse arguments
    if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 2)
        usage();
    boolean recursive = false;
    int dirArg = 0;
    if (args[0].equals("-r")) {
        if (args.length < 2)
            usage();
        recursive = true;
        dirArg++;
    }

    // register directory and process its events
    Path dir = Paths.get(args[dirArg]);
    new WatchDir(dir, recursive).processEvents();
}
}
```

I am developing an app in `Windows 7`, and deployment environment is `rhel 7.2`. At first, in both OS'es, whenever I copied a file, it fired one `ENTRY_CREATED` and then two `ENTRY_MODIFY`. The first `ENTRY_MODIFY` was at the beginning of copying, and the second `ENTRY_MODIFY` was at the end of copying. So I was able to understand the copying process was over. However, It only fires one `ENTRY_MODIFY` in `rhel 7.2` now. It still fires two `ENTRY_MODIFY` events in `Windows 7` though.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347632/getting-to-modify-events-on-changes-in-file) in `stackoverflow`. That question asks why two `ENTRY_MODIFY` are fired. It is not exactly my question, but one of its answers disputes what I'm asking. Sadly, there is no solution to my question in that dispute though.

Because there is no `ENTRY_MODIFY` fired at the end but only in the beginning of copying, I can not understand when the copying is finished. What do you think might be the cause for this? Can it be fixed, how can I understand the copying is finished? I can't change `rhel 7.2`, but anything other than that I would gladly accept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, please take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34718685/243373) on one way to know when your file was copied. HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have read your comment many times. However, I don't get how acquiring the file lock will help me understand when the copying process is over. Could you please exlain in more detail?

Comment: The file remains locked for RW access by other processes/threads as long as the copying process is busy. The code fragment in my answer tries to acquire a lock on that file (after you know about its existence by a `ENTRY_CREATED` event). The lock will be granted as soon as the file is no longer locked by the copying process. At that point the copying process is done.

Comment: Hello again, in the processEvents method I check ENTRY_CREATE event then I add your code block into that condition. However, it fires java.io.FileNotFoundExcepiton : the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Maybe I am using it wrong. Could you please add your code block in my example and see if it works. So that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just check if the file length is zero or not.
Here an example of

```
for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
    Path fileName = (Path) event.context();
    if("tomcat-users.xml".equals(fileName.toString())) {
        Path tomcatUsersXml = tomcatConf.resolve(fileName);
        if(tomcatUsersXml.toFile().length() > 0) {
            load(tomcatUsersXml);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: glad to find a genius on stackoverflow  - I had no luck finding anything I liked on the other thread but this is great `if (path.toFile().length() > 0)`

Comment: Does this also work if using BufferedWriter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DelayQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) to deduplicate the events.